# TinyXML TiXmlDocument::StreamOut unresolved at link time

Tags: c++, unresolved-external, tinyxml

Using TinyXML with TIXML_USE_STL (anyway doesn't change behavior)

My code

```
   TiXmlDocument doc(pszFileName);
   bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
   if (!loadOkay) {_ASSERTE(0); return(0);}
```

I just got one and only one unresolved:

> unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall
>   TiXmlDocument::StreamOut

The method is pure virtual in the TiXmlBase class and it look look like once derived in `TiXmlDocument`  it was forgotten to implement one.

Are users forced to implement their own ?

Feel that weird!

I haven't seen this being mention anywhere.

===========================   Solved =======================

The solution I got had 2 different version of tinyxml 2.4.5 and 2.5.1 the header must not be mixed.
Looks like upgrade to latest version is not an option.(in my case)

Comment: How are you linking in the library? Is it a static library, dynamic library, or did you just compile in the source with your own code?

Comment: static lib. I tried putting source in my projet, same. I did decide to make a dummy StreamOut  (I don't use it)

Comment: But I start wondering if I didn't get a project where there is a hidden mixup of tinyxml version.

Comment: Definitely very weird!

Comment: Well was my fault (or somebody else if I want to find a culprit) The project did mix 2 version of tinyxml. Header does not insure upward compatibility.